# Facebook Connect Dialog

Tags: facebook

I have a question with regards to the facebook dialog.

Basically, I would like to popup the dialog for the user to enter their credentials. Once they are authorized, I want the callback Url to be custom (but on same domain as specified in website url).

However, the FB.login method only takes 2 params: callback fcn and scope.

Any ideas how I can change the callback url once the user has logged in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, the redirect URL is set under the settings for your application inside the Facebook developer site.

Although, wouldn't just doing the redirect in the callback function work? e.g. with `window.location.href = "whatever"`?

Comment: No, I can do the redirect when the authentication succeeds that's fine, but I basically need to set the redirect_uri via FB.Login method call and there's no way I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) to detect when a user logs in.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
  // can redirect to your callback URL here if necessary
  alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
});
```